# IIS 8.5 on Win 2012 R2: Changes for Application Pool identity does not reflect?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5, application-pools

Running Win 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5.
When setting a custom identity to run a specific app pool (lets call it "App Pool 1") I get IMHO a really weird behavior.

When I click on App Pool 1 and then "Set Application Pool Defaults" > "Identity" > "Custom Account" and set a custom identity (a gMSA) and then just apply the changes by "OK"-ing out of the two windows and look at the main "Application Pools" window I still see the old identity that were running the app pool before I changed it.

This is even if I do "iisreset" and/or restart the server in question.
However if I were to double-check my settings by repeating the procedure above I can see that the custom identity I entered (gMSA) is still there.

So when going into App Pool 1 and viewing which identity is running the app pool I get the one I set; when viewing "Application Pools" which shows me all app pools I still see the old one.

Tried doing "iisreset", rebooting the entire server in question, checking event viewer and enabling the IIS logs there = nothing. Then just by random it changes from the old identity to the new one I set. Very weird. This is not after a restart or anything like that I just happens.

Another weird thing is that when I modify an app pool by setting a custom identity as described above the identities running all the default app pools (NET v2.0 etc.) changes to that custom identity as well.

So if I were to change Application Pool 1 to gmsaRandomGmsa that identity is running all the default app pools as well.

Would be grateful if someone experienced this before and know what causes it and how to solve it so changes reflect immediately.

Best Regards